# examples of using the Fredholm alternative explicitly

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider an elliptic partial differential equation

$$
\sum_{i,j} - \partial_j (a^{ij}(x) \partial_i u(x)) + \sum_i b^i(x) \partial_i u(x) + c(x)u(x) = f(x). 
$$

Under some reasonable assumption (e.g. $(a^{ij}(x))$ is uniformly elliptic and the coefficients are in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, etc.) one can apply the *Fredholm alternative*, which tells  us that a solution exists if and only if $f(x)$ is orthogonal to solutions of an adjoint homogeneous problem.

In principle, this means that for a given elliptic operator $L$ of the form above, one can write down an explicit finite set of linear conditions for the existence of a solution $Lu=f$. The proof is by abstract functional analysis of Fredholm operators.

I am looking for some nice explicit examples of such PDE plus analysis to see what exactly the obstructions are (i.e. a basis of solutions for the adjoint problem). When applied to the Poisson problem this guarantees uniqueness of solutions, but I am mostly interested in seeing examples where one has nontrivial obstructions, and can provably find all of them.

In particular, such examples will essentially boil down to finding all homogeneous solutions to an elliptic PDE with zero boundary data.

Answer (score 3):

What about the Neumann problem:
$$
-\Delta u(x) = f(x)
$$ with boundary condition
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial n}=0.
$$
This equation is solvable if and only if $\int_\Omega f =0$, since the constant functions are the solutions of the homogeneous problem. I think, this is studied in detail in Evans' book on pdes.